# videos landing in the ‘Raw landing zone’ start to be processed before the upload has finished

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

So I have an issue, we are uploading raw video files into the blob storage using Iperius back-up, the files are 20 mins long, where they are then processed with an AI program

We are enow encountering a bug with the videos landing in the ‘Raw landing zone’ and start to be processed before the upload has finished.

Anyone have any ideas why this might be ?

There are no errors and the uploads eventually complete. The BlobCreated event is designed by Microsoft to fire at the end of an upload, so our use is inline with recommendations. Is it due to how the Iperius tool invokes the blob API ?

The BlobCreated trigger fires correctly if we use a different tool such as azcopy or the portal to upload videos to the same container.

Answer (score 0):

> Encountering a bug with the videos landing in the ‘Raw landing zone’ and start to be processed before the upload has finished.

- Mostly, Iperius back-up start sending data in smaller parts rather than waiting for the entire file to be uploaded before initiating the transfer. As a result, the BlobCreated event might trigger as soon as the first chunk is uploaded.

I already tried in my environment as a result I didn't face any issues in the operation.

[image]

- Explore other event triggers provided by Blob storage or Iperius, which might be more suitable for the use case. for example, custom event handler that waits for the completion of the upload before starting the processing.

**Iperius logs:**
[image]

Below is the Raw landing zone with successfully uploaded file with no obstacles.

[image]

As you said that using different tools like `azcopy` or uploading through portal directly is better.

- I had tried a python code which connects to the blob container for the file transfer from local to cloud storage.

```py
import os
import time
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

# Replace with your actual connection string and container name
connection_string = "yours_connection_string"
container_name = "test"

# Replace with the local path to your video file
local_file_path = "your_local_file_path_file.mp4"
file_name = os.path.basename(local_file_path)

def upload_file_to_blob():
    try:
        # Create a BlobServiceClient using the provided connection string
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

        # Create a container client to interact with the container
        container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

        # Upload the file to the container as a blob
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(file_name)
        with open(local_file_path, "rb") as data:
            blob_client.upload_blob(data)

        print(f"File '{file_name}' uploaded successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    upload_file_to_blob()
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Container:**
[image]